# How handle this type of data into Array - JAVA

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

In my app i have a function that give me that type of data:

a Year(int) and a String associated to that year (years can have associated more string):

> 2016 - "1A2B3C"
>
> 2009 - "8DF56R"
>
> 2009 - "8E4I1J"
>
> 2013 - "P6F2T8"
>
> 2009 - "4K6J5U"

I want create an array of String for each Year, than sort the Years for increasing years. Like this:

> 2009 - "8DF56R" "8E4I1J" "4K6J5U"
>
> 2013 - "P6F2T8"
>
> 2016 - "1A2B3C"

The Year should be the index,
How can i retrieve that output?

Sorry for the noob question but I tried array of array, ArrayList and Map but i'm probably missing something.

Comment: Map should have worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a `Map` of `List`s like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> = new TreeMap<>();
```

and you can fill up the `List`s associated with an `Integer` key (date). The `TreeMap` sorts your keys according to their natural ordering (ascending by default if I recall it right).

You can also create a custom `Comparator` if he default is not satisfactory for you

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution, I added a piece of code for add the data can you check if is right?

Comment: Your code does not compile. You might want to use the `containsKey` method on `Map` to check whether you have the given year in it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is create a Class T containing your informations (year, String, etc.) and implementing Comparable interface. Method compareTo(T) will compare years. By this way you can handle more informations.
Object of this type can be inserted in SortedSet, for example, or a List used with Collections.sort or with Java8 Stream.